# How to insert data from HTML page as sub documents in mongoDB in Mean-stack application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am trying to insert data as sub document in a MEANSTACK application.
Below is the schema:

```
 var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', mongoose.Schema({
    weekstart : { type:Date, default: Date.now},
    weekend : { type:Date, default: Date.now},
  //  user : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee' }],
    timesheet:[{
    project:{ type:String},
    activity:{ type:String},
    day:{type: String},
    hours:{type: Number}
        }]

}));
```

In the above, I want to insert the data from the HTML page to activity, project, day and hours.

The API return for this purpose is:

```
app.post('/api/employees', function(req, res){
    Employee.create( req.body, function(err, employees,time){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
        res.json(employees);
        console.log(employees);
        console.log(time);
    });
});
```

The service is:

```
$scope.addTimesheet = function(data){
        $scope.time = [];
        //var id = $routeParams.id;
        $http.post('/api/employees/', $scope.employee).then(function(response){
        $scope.employee = response.data;
        $http.get('/api/employees/' ).success(function(response){
        $scope.time =  response.timesheet;
        window.location.href = '/';
        });
    });
    }
```

The HTML page is:

```
<tbody>
     <tr id="tablerow">
          <td>  
                <select name="Project stream" ng-model="time.timesheet.project">
                    <option value="">Project Stream</option>
                    <option value="Drones">Drones</option>
                    <option value="Virtual Reality">Virtual Reality</option>
                    <option value="Augmented Reality">Augmented Reality</option>
                    <option value="Arch – Automation">Arch – Automation</option>
                    <option value="Arch – Devops">Arch – Devops</option>
                    <option value="Voice">Voice</option>
                </select>
          </td>
          <td> 
                <select name="Activities" ng-model="time.timesheet.activity">
                     <option value="">Activities</option>
                     <option value="Research">Research</option>
                     <option value="Development">Development</option>
                     <option value="Test/Deploy">Test/Deploy</option>
                     <option value="Demo">Demo</option>
                </select>
           </td>
           <td> 
                <select name="Week" ng-model="time.timesheet.day">
                    <option value="">Week</option>
                    <option value='Monday'>Monday</option>
                    <option value='Tuesday'>Tuesday</option>
                    <option value='Wednesday'>Wednesday</option>
                    <option value='Thursday'>Thursday</option>
                    <option value='Friday'>Friday</option>
                    <option value='Saturday'>Saturday</option>
                </select>
           </td>
           <td>
               <center><input type = "number" min="0.5" max="9" style="width: 55px" required ng-model="$parent.time.timesheet.hours"></center>
           </td>
           <!-- <td><center><input type = "number" min="0.5" max="9" style="width: 55px" required ></center></td>
                <td><center><input type = "number" min="0.5" max="9" style="width: 55px" required ></center></td>
                <td><center><input type = "number" min="0.5" max="9" style="width: 55px" required ></center></td>
                <td><center><input type = "number" min="0.5" max="9" style="width: 55px" required ></center></td>
                <td><center><input type = "number" min="0.5" max="9" style="width: 55px" required ></center>
                </td>
           -->         
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>
               <center><input type = "text" ></center>
           </td>
           <td>
               <center><input type = "text"  ></center>
           </td>
           <td>
               <center><input type = "text" ></center>
           </td>
           <td>
               <center><input type = "text"  style="width: 55px" required ></center>
           </td>
           <!-- <td><center><input type = "text"  style="width: 55px" required ></center></td>
                <td><center><input type = "text"  style="width: 55px" required ></center></td>
                <td><center><input type = "text"  style="width: 55px" required ></center></td>
                <td><center><input type = "text"  style="width: 55px" required ></center>
                </td>
            -->
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me in this? seeking for help..